# no-return-assign - when to disable

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, eslint

I am trying to pass ids in this object array:

```
const children = [{name: Jack, age: 8}, {name: Joe, age: 6}];
children.forEach((child) => (child.id = v4()));
```

I keep getting eslint error `no-return-assign` this is really bugging me (pun intended)

I tried:

```
children.forEach(child => child.id = v4());

children.forEach((child) => (child.id = v4())); 

children.forEach(child => (child.id = v4()));

children.forEach((child) => {
    return child.id = v4()
});
```

None work.

Should I disable eslint? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Well, you can disable the eslint rule, or don't return an assignment, eg, try: `children.forEach(child => { child.id = v4() }) // Note the lack of return, and the use of {} instead of ()`.

Comment: With yours i got `Assignment to property of function parameter 'child' no param reassign`

Comment: This is an eslint rule that is complaining about mutating the function parameter. You can turn that off or you'll need to use map and create a new copy of of the array instead, eg: `children = children.map(child => { return {...child, id: v4()}; })`

Comment: good answer. I can do this i guess:
`for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i += 1) {
        children[i].id = v4();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well don't return anything from your callback function. Just write

```
children.forEach(child => {
    child.id = v4();
});
```

or even simpler

```
for (const child of children) {
    child.id = v4();
}
```

Comment: The first example got: `Assignment to property of function parameter 'child' no-param-reassign`

Second example is great